# How to scan and autocrop?

Tags: windows-7, windows, scanning

I have windows 7 64bit and HP Printer, I used to have windows XP and the HP software use to autocrop the image, with windows 7 there is no option to autocrop a picture once you are done scanning, you can still do it but you must choose and crop it by your self,
is there any other option or 3rd party software that can scan and automatically crop the image?

Comment: photoshop will auto crop and straighten, Myself I find that auto anything is never going to do things the exact way I want. Learning how to do a quick crop and arbitrary rotate in about Any photo editing program has always been best. even irfanview and xnview (simple freeware) can handle these operations.  Human 1 computer 0

Comment: Thanks, irfanview and xnview both works, I did try them at first but it didn't work, but now I tried it again and all good. when you go to "File" and "Select Twain" , I need to choose "WIA-HP Officeject" as the source and this works, i chose before "HP officeJect" as source and it didn't work. thank you